# What is the Sanskrit for "Universal Gate"

Tags: texts, lotus-sutra

The "Universal Gate" is referred to in chapter 25 of the Lotus Sutra. I've been trying to find the Sanskrit for this, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "samantamukha."

See here: http://www.dsbcproject.org/canon-text/content/54/481

You'll notice that it's chapter 25 of the Chinese, but chapter 24 of the Sanskrit. This is because the Chinese translation splits one of the chapters into two chapters.